# Can Tor work on dial-up?

Tags: speed

I think it is possible to connect to Tor on dial-up on Linux. Is it possible? Because I don't have access to dial-up Internet in my home, I ask this question.

Comment: Do you just want to connect to the Tor network, or do you want to run a relay as well?

Comment: I want to connect to the Tor network.